# How to emit signals in another class in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, signals

We can emit signals in the class defining the signals easily by `emit signal_a()` like

```
class A
{
signals:
    signal_a();

public:
    void fun()
    {
        do_something();
        emit signal_a();
        do_something();
    }
};
```

However, How to emit signals in another class in Qt? For example

```
class B
{
public:
    void fun()
    {
        do_something();
        (*a) emit signal_a(); // ???
        do_something();
    }

A* a;
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Qt5, you can just do

```
emit a->signal_a();
```

`emit` is an empty macro and signals are set public (the `signals` "keyword is a macro that becomes `public`)

Comment: Thank you very much. But a typo here. Should be `emit a.signal_a()` in my case.

Comment: yeah but you shouldn't be keeping QObjects by value

Comment: @ratchetfreak why not?

Comment: Could you provide a sample, how you can emit signals from amother class? Signals are protected methods.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Modify my question by following your suggestion. I am also wondering why? Is it because of the QObject's memory management?

Comment: @DmitrySazonov they are public according to [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/signalsandslots.html#signals)

Comment: `Signals are emitted by an object when its internal state has changed in some way that might be interesting to the object's client or owner. Signals are public access functions and can be emitted from anywhere, but we recommend to only emit them from the class that defines the signal and its subclasses.`

Comment: @khajvah then you should add that it is valid only for Qt5, but not for Qt4.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Ok, sorry. I am new to qt. Have never used Qt4.

Answer (score 11):

You can't emit signals directly, because signals are **protected** methods (in Qt4). There are several ways to do what you want:

1. create public method in class A, that will emit necessary signals
2. create signal in class B and connect it to a signal in class A

You should remember, that classes with signals must interhit QObject and contain Q_OBJECT macro.

Comment: It can also be accomplished through QMetaObject::invokeMethod

Comment: Ofc, but it is big overhead

Answer (score 4):

Qt signals are normal methods. The 'emit' keyword will expand to empty string, so just call a.signal_a();